# Import array from CSV to Fusion Table in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables, import-from-csv

By this code I am able to import a CSV file into a Fusion Table row by row.
There is a way to import the whole array in one step without cycling line by line?
The code running in Google Apps Script.

```js
function myCSV_FT() {
      //Needs activate FT API in Resources menu
      
      // Convert CSV in array
      var csvUrl = "http://www.mysite.it/myfile.csv";
      var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);
      
      //cycling array and put value in FT
      for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
        var csvInput = csvData[i][0] + ',' + csvData[i][1];
        var mediaData = Utilities.newBlob(csvInput, 'application/octet-stream');
        FusionTables.Table.importRows('FusionTableID', mediaData);
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a change as follows.

From :

```
for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
  var csvInput = csvData[i][0] + ',' + csvData[i][1];
  var mediaData = Utilities.newBlob(csvInput, 'application/octet-stream');
  FusionTables.Table.importRows('FusionTableID', mediaData);
}
```

To :

```
var csvInput = '';
for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
  csvInput += csvData[i][0] + ',' + csvData[i][1] + '\n';
} 
var mediaData = Utilities.newBlob(csvInput, 'application/octet-stream');
FusionTables.Table.importRows('FusionTableID', mediaData);
```

I always use Fusion Table by importing strings like above.

Comment: Thank you. A simple solution, but very very very fast. Time execution for csv file with 16 rows: 18s vs 1s. Csv file with 1200 rows: overflow for max execution time vs 2s!

Comment: Thank you, too.I'm happy to be useful for you.